# Arduino reading data from 82 different sources

Tags: arduino, input

I want to make my own electric darts. Whenever a dart will hit the dartboard I need to get the dart location to my Arduino so I can count the score. The problem I am facing is that the dartboard has 82 different places where a dart can land. For example if a dart hits the bullseye it will trigger the switch and I need some component that will send information into the Arduino that the bullseye was hit and I can add 50 to the score. But since there are so many inputs I don't know any component that can do it. My idea was something like reverse multiplexing, but when I started thinking more about it I don't think that is possible.

Do you have any ideas how I can achieve such a thing? And which component I need to read that much data?

Comment: look at matrix keypads

Comment: What kind of Arduino do you have? Uno?

Comment: "*I am going to make my own electric darts.*" I think you mean you are going to make your own electric **dart board**, not darts. How are you going to detect a dart "contact"? (I think you should forget all the software problems until you have a reliable working "contact".) How are you going to align these zones precisely with the wire frame? Electronic dart boards are [readily available](https://www.google.com/search?q=electronic+dart+board).

Comment: Sending info is easy. Detecting position on a std. dart board, impossible unless you have a dual camera with zone recognition software. Try something else.

Comment: I think you have the cart way before the horse here. Figure out how you will detect the location of each dart. What if multiple darts hit the bullseye? I think this is enormously harder than you realize, and starting a project by saying that you will use an Arduino is a bad way to begin.

Comment: A pretty hacked but probably working solution would be to use an old PS2 keyboard, use your contacts instead of the keybutton and use a PS2 libary from arduino.

Comment: To elaborate on @jsotola's comment: Look at how keyboards and keypads are encoded, and consider that a standard dartboard is more suited to polar coordinates than rectangular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a IC which is able to store 8 parallel inputs and shifts them out over a single serial output.

The [74HC165](https://www.nexperia.com/products/analog-logic-ics/i-o-expansion-logic/shift-registers/74HC165DB.html) is such an IC. You need 10 of them (plus two regular inputs). You could connect the ICs in series for shifting out all of  the 80 inputs with one signal.